# Offline server that hosts push notifications to Android and IOS

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

Heya im trying to create an app that people can use to send push notifications to eachohter. The only catch is that the users will be working in an offline server within a company. They won't have access to the internet so connecting to something like Azure Notification Hubs is not possible. The only thing I have been able to find is, that it is possible to create a server from which you could send push notifications. Only problem is, I can't find how to send these notifications. If anyone has any kind of clue how I could send the notifications to the server and then to the users, I would be forever gratefull. Thanks!

Comment: **Offline** server definitely out-of-science tool that every developer dream about. You just need to create and deploy normal **online** server and receive requests from mobile devices there, then send push notifications on listeners (other mobile devices) from there. If I understand correctly what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Just create your own local(*local network) push notification api(GCM) and add it your app. Make both devices connect to same local network, you can achieve it

Comment: For users to receive OS native push notifications they need connection to corresponding services of Google and Apple. They sure can receive such native messages via 3G/4G/LTE. If they can't receive such messages while being connected to local network then local push notification server will not help because notifications will be stuck at Apple/Google servers until mobile device leave local restricted network.

Comment: So if I understand you guys correctly, its basicly not possible to have a completely offline service. And there always needs to be some kind of connection to Google or Apple to be able to send push notifications?

Comment: Yes, you need network to send and receive those notifications.

Comment: Alright thank you all for the information (: